# Error when requesting user registration, I can not remove the null error?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-validator

I have a problem implementing a user controller in a rest api, spring boot:

The problem is the following, it is all configured to receive the `json`, but when I put the `json` I have a return, `403 bindexception`, accusing that 5 points sent in the body of the request are null, and they are not!
Below is the code, the request and the response.

If someone can tell me why the api does not accept it I will be very grateful!

the error:

```
Resolved [org.springframework.validation.BindException: org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 5 errors<EOL>Field error in object 'dadosCadastroUsuario' on field 'senha': rejected value [null]; codes [NotBlank.dadosCadastroUsuario.senha,NotBlank.senha,NotBlank.java.lang.String,NotBlank]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [dadosCadastroUsuario.senha,senha]; arguments []; default message [senha]]; default message [não deve estar em branco]<EOL>Field error in object 'dadosCadastroUsuario' on field 'endereco': rejected value [null]; codes [NotNull.dadosCadastroUsuario.endereco,NotNull.endereco,NotNull.br.com.farmacos.endereco.DadosEndereco,NotNull]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [dadosCadastroUsuario.endereco,endereco]; arguments []; default message [endereco]]; default message [não deve ser nulo]<EOL>Field error in object 'dadosCadastroUsuario' on field 'login': rejected value [null]; codes [NotBlank.dadosCadastroUsuario.login,NotBlank.login,NotBlank.java.lang.String,NotBlank]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [dadosCadastroUsuario.login,login]; arguments []; default message [login]]; default message [não deve estar em branco]<EOL>Field error in object 'dadosCadastroUsuario' on field 'email': rejected value [null]; codes [NotBlank.dadosCadastroUsuario.email,NotBlank.email,NotBlank.java.lang.String,NotBlank]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [dadosCadastroUsuario.email,email]; arguments []; default message [email]]; default message [não deve estar em branco]<EOL>Field error in object 'dadosCadastroUsuario' on field 'nome': rejected value [null]; codes [NotBlank.dadosCadastroUsuario.nome,NotBlank.nome,NotBlank.java.lang.String,NotBlank]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [dadosCadastroUsuario.nome,nome]; arguments []; default message [nome]]; default message [não deve estar em branco]]
```

the code:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("usuarios")
@Tag(name= "Usuários", description = "Endpoints para controle de usuários")
public class UsuarioController {
    
    @Autowired
    private UsuarioRepository repository;
    
    @PostMapping
    @Transactional
    @Operation(summary = "Cadastre um usuário",
    description ="Cadastre um usuário", 
    tags = {"Usuários"},
            responses = {
                    @io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.responses.ApiResponse( responseCode = "200",content = @Content(
                            mediaType = "application/json")),
                    @io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.responses.ApiResponse( responseCode = "400",content = @Content),
                    @io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.responses.ApiResponse( responseCode = "401",content = @Content),
                    @io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.responses.ApiResponse( responseCode = "404",content = @Content),
                    @io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.responses.ApiResponse( responseCode = "500",content = @Content),
            })
    public ResponseEntity<DadosDetalhamentoUsuario> cadastrar(@RequestBody @Valid DadosCadastroUsuario dados, 
            UriComponentsBuilder uriBuilder){
        
        var usuario = new Usuario(dados);
        
        repository.save(usuario);
        
        var uri = uriBuilder.path("/usuarios/{id}").buildAndExpand(usuario.getId()).toUri();
        
        return ResponseEntity.created(uri).body(new DadosDetalhamentoUsuario(usuario));
    }

}
```

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfigurations {
    
    @Autowired
    private SecurityFilter filtroDeSeguranca;

    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http.csrf().disable()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and().authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/login").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/usuarios").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().addFilterBefore(filtroDeSeguranca, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration configuration) throws Exception {
        return configuration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    WebSecurityCustomizer webSecurityCustomizer() {
        return (web) -> web.ignoring().requestMatchers("/swagger-ui/**", "/v3/api-docs/**");
    }
    
}
```

```
public record DadosCadastroUsuario(
        
        @NotBlank
        String nome,
        @NotBlank
        String login,   
        @NotBlank
        @Size(min=6, max=30)
        String senha,   
        @NotBlank
        @Email
        String email,
        @CPF
        String cpf,
        @NotNull
        @Valid
        DadosEndereco endereco
        ) {

}

public record DadosDetalhamentoUsuario(Long id, String nome, String login, String email, String cpf, Endereco endereco) {
```

```
public DadosDetalhamentoUsuario(Usuario usuario) {
        this(usuario.getId(), usuario.getNome(), usuario.getLogin(), usuario.getEmail(), usuario.getCpf(), usuario.getEndereco());
    }
}

@Table(name = "usuarios")
@Entity(name = "Usuario")
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(of ="id")

public class Usuario implements UserDetails{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    public Usuario (DadosCadastroUsuario dados) {
        this.nome = dados.nome();
        this.login = dados.login();
        this.senha = dados.senha();
        this.email = dados.email();
        this.cpf = dados.cpf();
        this.ativo = true;
        this.endereco = new Endereco(dados.endereco());
    }
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    
    private String nome;
    private String login;
    private String senha;
    private String email;
    private String cpf;
    private boolean ativo;
    
    @Embedded
    private Endereco endereco;
    
    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return List.of(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));
    }
    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return senha;
    }
    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return login;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

```
create table usuarios
(
   id bigint not null auto_increment,
   login varchar (100) not null,
   senha varchar (255) not null,
   ativo tinyint,
   nome varchar (100) not null,
   email varchar (100) not null,
   cpf varchar (100) not null,
   cep varchar (100) not null,
   uf char (2) not null,
   cidade varchar (100) not null,
   bairro varchar (100) not null,
   complemento varchar (100),
   numero varchar (100),
   primary key (id)
);
```

I hope the json works and I can register the user

Answer (score 0):

For the request Matchers you should use a wildcard.
Your endpoint `/usuarios/{id}` does not match `/usarios`, but it would match `/usarios/**`

So change `requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/usuarios").permitAll()` to `requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/usuarios*").permitAll()` in your `securityFilterChain` Bean.